# Predicate logic Vs propositional logic: a specific example

Tags: predicate-logic

Consider the following argument.

1) People who write novels are more sensitive than people who play soccer. 2) Alf writes novels. 3) Brian plays soccer.

Conclusion: 4) Alf is more sensitive than Brian.

Here is how you formalise this argument using predicate logic (many thanks to Mauro Allegranza):

1) ∀x∀y((Nx & Sy) ⊃ Mxy) 2) Na 3) Sb Conclusion: 4) Mab

M= more sensitive than N= writes novels S= plays soccer a= Alf b= Brian

If I had to formalise (1)-(4) using propositional logic it would be: 
 1) p 2) q 3) r Conclusion: 4) s.

That is, we would have 4 different propositions with no links between them. Am I right?

Thank you very much

Fish

Answer (score 0):

Well, no, not really.

A better answer would be to say that **propositional logic CANNOT formalize that kind of reasoning**.

Comment: Yes of course; but if you had to formalise this reasoning the answer would be the one I propose.

Comment: If I had to formalize the reasoning, the answer would be "it's impossible". Just as if I "had to" use the real numbers to solve $x^2+1=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Something you *could* do in propositional logic is this:

$A$: Alf plays soccer

$B$: Brian plays soccer

$C$: Alf writes novels

$D$ : Brian  writes novels

$E$: Alf is more senitive than Alf

$F$: Alf is more sensitive than Brian

$G$: Brian is more sensitiv than Alf

$H$: Brian is more sensitive than Brian

With these, you could take the first statement, and *at least as it relates to Alf and Brian*, capture that with:

1. $((A \land C) \to E) \land ((A \land D) \to G) \land ((B \land C) \to F) \land ((B \land D) \to H)$

And of course we also have:

2. $C$
3. $B$
4. $F$

And now you can infer it. Yes, ths statement 1 obviously does not capture the whole universal English statement as it pertains to *any* two people, but as far as we are interested in Alf and Brian, it does the job.